# Java - Counting Occurrences in a Linked List

Tags: java, eclipse, linked-list, repeat, counting

As part of an assignment, I have to write a method that will print out repeating values in a linked list, as well as how many times they occur. Below is the method `printRepeats()` which uses the helper method `countRepeats(ListNode node)`.

The issue is that the output of my method prints repeating values over and over again. For example, in a list with values `1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6`, the output is `1 (Occurences = 3) 1 (Occurences = 3) 1 (Occurences = 3) 6 (Occurences = 2) 6 (Occurences = 2)`.  Any value that repeats should only print once. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
public class LinkedList
{
    private ListNode first;

    public void printRepeats()
    {
        String ans = "";
        ListNode temp = first;
        while(temp != null)
        {
            if(countRepeats(temp) > 1 && ans.indexOf((int)temp.getValue()) == -1)
            {
                ans += temp.getValue();
                System.out.print(temp.getValue() + " (Occurences = " + countRepeats(temp) + ") ");
            }
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        if(ans.length() == 0)
            System.out.print("None of the elements repeat.");
    }

    private int countRepeats(ListNode node)
    {
        ListNode temp = first;
        int count = 0;
        while(temp != null)
        {
            if((int)temp.getValue() == (int)node.getValue())
                count++;
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a HashMap<Integer, Integer>, where the key is the number in the list, and the value is its number of occurrences.

Comment: What your specification? Have you any runtime limits or can you use other datastructure to solve this problem?

Comment: @CRC No data structure other than linked list can be used; as far as runtime limits, the code should be as efficient as possible but it's not a prime concern.

Comment: @JBNizet I am in AP Computer Science AB at my school, we haven't learned HashMaps yet.

Comment: The store the number you have just counted and printed in another LinkedList, and skip a number if it's already in this other LinkedList. Or, before counting a number, check if it's not before it in the linked list.

Comment: check what counting sort is. This is the same problem. You will not just solve your assignment but will learn about algorithms as well.

Comment: @JBNizet How would this differ from my current `String` variable `ans`? Also, simply checking the variable beforehand wouldn't solve the issue since repeats can occur later in the list. For example, `1 2 3 4 5 2 6 7 2`.

Comment: Well, it would work. First problem: you count first, and then check if the number is in ans. You should first check, then count. Second, suppose your list contains the number 678987. You're appending it to ans. Then, to know if it has been met already, you do `ans.indexOf(number) == -1`. But indexOf() takes a `char`as argument, and checks if the char (lke 'a' or '0') is in the string. So that doesn't make sense. A STring is not a collection of integers. A LinkedList can be.

Comment: @JBNizet Nice, I didn't think of multiple digit numbers.

Comment: Even with single digit numbers, it doesn't work. The integer 1 and the char '1' don't have the same value. The integer value of '1' is 49. See http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you must not use any other data structures than a LinkedList, you could:

- Create another ListNode element as the first element of a list called "repeatedElements", that must contain pairs element/repetitions of such element.
- When counting the repetitions of a single element, insert the element and the number of repetitions it has in "repeatedElements" list.
- Before counting the number of repetitions of an element, sweep the repeatedElements list for the element. If the element is present, DO NOT print the output. If it is not, repeat your code as usual.

The system I described will contain more information than the specifically required (the number of repetitions of each element is stored), but it is likely that it will be needed again.

Comment: Why would I have to store the number of repetitions _and_ the value? Couldn't I just store the value that is repeated and traverse `repeatedElements` each iteration to make sure that my current element is not in `repeatedElements`? Based on my current knowledge, I think what you are saying would require a Doubly LinkedList, which is a structure we have not learned yet.

Comment: It is true, you do not HAVE TO include both data in the linked list, although it would be a good practice, to avoid future recomputation. However, you would not need a Double Linked List to store both values. A linked list is a mapping structure, that points to a series of cells containing values. Each cell can contain any amount of values. The ListNode object can store, for example, an object or array instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

For counting occurrences you need to maintain track record of visited node also like if you have already count any node then need not to pick again those come on link list. Below program clearly explains this-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomLinkList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode linkedList = new ListNode(15);
        linkedList.next =new ListNode(67);
        linkedList.next.next =new ListNode(15);
        linkedList.next.next.next =new ListNode(65);
        linkedList.next.next.next.next =new ListNode(13);
        linkedList.next.next.next.next.next =new ListNode(98);
        linkedList.next.next.next.next.next.next =new ListNode(33);
        linkedList.next.next.next.next.next.next.next =new ListNode(29);
        linkedList.next.next.next.next.next.next.next.next =new ListNode(15);
        ListNode printList = linkedList;
        System.out.println("Custom Link List is ::: ");
        while (printList.next != null){
            System.out.printf("%d ",printList.info);
            printList = printList.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
         CustomLinkList.occurancesOfElement(linkedList);
    }

    public static void occurancesOfElement(ListNode listNode){
        ArrayList<Integer> visitedNode = new ArrayList();
        while(listNode !=null){
            ListNode node = listNode;
            int count = 0;
            while (node !=null)
            {
                if(listNode.info == node.info && !visitedNode.contains(node.info)) {
                    count++;
                }
                node = node.next;
            }
            if(!visitedNode.contains(listNode.info))
            System.out.println("Occurences of : "+listNode.info+" is "+ count);
            
            visitedNode.add(listNode.info);
            listNode = listNode.next;
        }
    }
}

class ListNode {
    int info;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int info){
        this.info = info;
        next = null;
    }
}

class DoublyListNode {
    int info;
    DoublyListNode previous;
    DoublyListNode next;
}
}
```